# Issue setting up spfx project

Tags: spfx, npm

I am not able to generate a yo project using `@microsoft/generator-sharepoint`. The menu simply freezes at the following step -

> which type of client-side component to create?

arrows key don't work anymore, nor does `Ctrl + C`

[image]

I have tried reinstalling eveything a few times over. It doesnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve by directly passing the parameters in the command.

`yo @microsoft/sharepoint --solutionName "hello-world" --framework "react" --componentType "webpart" --componentName "HelloWorld" --componentDescription "HelloWorld web part"`

[Source](http://%20%20[2]:%20https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/toolchain/scaffolding-projects-using-yeoman-sharepoint-generator)